# expressjs doesn't wait till query is done

Tags: express, asynchronous, elasticsearch

I am using expressjs to retrieve data from elasticsearch and send back to my angular app at the front end. Currently I am facing a problem since expressjs doesn't wait until the query execution is finished. I searched for a solution for that and the community says use "Promise or Sync". But I cant figure out where should I use it. I tried to use it but I am getting errors.

This is where I am receiving the request from the frontend and calling the elasticsearch query for send the response.

```
api.post('/clsDependencies', (req, res) => {
  classDependencies(req.body.className);
  res.json(messages);
});
```

This the function for querying the elasticsearch.

```
function classDependencies(csName) {
let body = {
size: 20,
from: 0,
query: {
  match: {
    ClassName: {
      query: csName
    }
  }
}
};
search('testclass', body)
.then(results => {
results.hits.hits.forEach((hit, index) => hit._source.dependencies.forEach(
  function(myClass){
    messages.push({text: myClass.methodSignature , owner: `\t${++nmb} - 
 ${myClass.dependedntClass}`});
  }))})
 .catch(console.error);
 };
```

Expected data gets initialized to the variable(messages) which I am trying to send back to the front end. But the variable doesn't get initialized at the time when response is send back. What Should I do to wait till the query execution finish before send back the data to frontend.

**EDIT**

messages is defined outside of both functions.

```
function classDirectory(className) {
let body = {
size: 20,
from: 0,
query: {
  match: {
    ClassName: {
      query: className
    }
  }
 }
};
return search('testclass', body).then(results => {
results.hits.hits.forEach((hit, index) => 
getDirectories(hit._source.JarFileName));
return messages;
 })
.catch(function(err) {
  // log the error, but keep the promise rejected
  console.error(err);
  throw err;
 });
};

function getDirectories(jarName) {
let body = {
size: 20,
from: 0,
query: {
  match: {
    jarFileName: {
      query: jarName
    }
  }
}
};
return search('testjar', body).then(results => {
results.hits.hits.forEach((hit, index) => 
    messages.push({text: hit._source.jarFileName , owner: `\t${++nmb} - 
  ${hit._source.directory}`})
   );
   return messages;
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
   // log the error, but keep the promise rejected
   console.error(err);
   throw err;
   });
  };
```

Comment: fix function names classDirectory and classDependency

Comment: Thnx I edited that, But that wasn't the problem I copied and pasted the wrong method.

Comment: okay, then what should I do to make the script waits until search() method is done?

Comment: @rayancarlon - As I explained in my answer, you can't make the script wait.  Instead, you have to use completion callbacks and/or promise notifications to know when search is done and do `res.json()` only when that completion is signaled.  Details in my answer.

Comment: @jfriend yeah I trying to understand what you have done, I am new to expressjs and have to learn a lot. Thnk you once again.

Comment: Please format your code appropriately with appropriate indentation when you put code into questions.  I cannot make any sense of your code without putting it in a code formatter and fixing the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript interpreter does not "block" when you make asynchronous calls.  This has absolutely nothing to do with Express.

Your call to `search()` is non-blocking so while it's in process, `classDependencies()` returns and the rest of your code continues to run.  This is the way asynchronous calls in Javascript work.

If you want to call `res.json()` when `classDependencies()` is done, then return a promise from it and call `res.json()` when that promise resolves.

You could do something like this:

```
api.post('/clsDependencies', (req, res) => {
  classDependencies(req.body.className).then(messages => {
      res.json(messages);
  }).catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send(something here);
  });
});

function classDependencies(csName) {
    let body = {
        size: 20,
        from: 0,
        query: {
            match: {
                ClassName: {
                    query: csName
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return search('testclass', body).then(results => {
        let messages = [];
        results.hits.hits.forEach((hit, index) => hit._source.dependencies.forEach(function(myClass) {
            messages.push({
                text: myClass.methodSignature,
                owner: `\t${++nmb} - ${myClass.dependedntClass}`
            });
        }));
        // make messages be the resolved value of the returns promise
        return messages;
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // log the error, but keep the promise rejected
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    });
};
```

Comment: I added a another code snippet in my question, I followed your answer and edited my another code which does the query from two functions to get the data I want, Is that way correct? It works fine But the way that code works won't seem correct.

Comment: @rayancarlon - That's not how this place works.  You don't keep adding more questions into your question.  I think you agree that your original question has been answered.  If you have a new question, then please ask a new question.  I defined `messages` as a local variable and made it be the resolved value of the promise because that's a safe way to handle data in async code and you did not show any definition for it in your original question.

Comment: I posted a new question can you please take a look at that.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874659/propper-way-to-use-expressjs-promise)

Comment: @rayancarlon - Just curious why you removed the accepted answer check from this almost 3 months later without any further comment?

Comment: I want to delete this question or delete this account that's why,

Comment: @rayancarlon - So you want to unreward those who you previously rewarded for helping you?  That makes a lot of sense.  If you want to delete your account, just delete your account.  You don't have to go undo everything you did on the site.  As far as I know, you can't delete individual questions that already have answers.

Comment: @rayancarlon - Also, why are you leaving?  Did you not find any help here?

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't know so I requested to delete this account but seems like I should wait for 24hours

Comment: Some personal issues I don't wanna tell in public. But your answer really helped me man. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
api.post('/clsDirectory', (req, res) => {
  classDependency(req.body.className, res);
});


function classDependency(csName, cb) {
let body = {
size: 20,
from: 0,
query: {
  match: {
     ClassName: {
      query: csName
    }
  }
}
};
search('testclass', body)
.then(results => {
results.hits.hits.forEach((hit, index) => 
hit._source.dependencies.forEach(
  function(myClass){
    messages.push({text: myClass.methodSignature , owner: `\t${++nmb} - 
 ${myClass.dependedntClass}`});
  }));
  cb.json(messages);
 })
 .catch(console.error);
 };
```

Comment: I got this error when I tried your code,  ```TypeError: cb is not a function```

Comment: First off, there's really no point in introducing a callback, when you are already using promises.  Just keep using promises (see my answer for one way to do that).  Second, I don't think it will work passing `res.json` as the callback.  It will probably lose its association with the `res` object.

Comment: @jfriend00 on spot. Thanks